# How to use Xpath to filter out date field in Wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, xpath, import, wpallimport

I am using the WP All Import plugin to import a csv file with thousands of records every day but I don't need all of them, only the ones that have been updated. There is a "last modified" column in the csv file which i'd like to compare to today's date and filter out anything that doesn't match.

Wp all import let's you do this using xpath, but I have no idea how to reference today's date in it, can anyone help?

[WP All Import xpath screen.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbVhK.png)

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

XPath 2.0 solution (paste it in the XPath field) to keep records of the day:

```
/node[@last_modified[concat(substring(.,7,4),substring(.,4,2),substring(.,1,2))=string(format-date(current-date(),"[Y][M01][D01]"))]]
```

We extract the date with substring, convert the current date (XPath 2.0 functions : not sure WP supports it) to string and we compare them. We finally put this condition between brackets.

**EDIT** : OK. last_modified is an element not an attribute. So just remove the "@" from the expression :

```
/node[last_modified[concat(substring(.,7,4),substring(.,4,2),substring(.,1,2))=string(format-date(current-date(),"[Y][M01][D01]"))]]
```

If it doesn't work just add '[1]' after the element :

```
/node[last_modified[1][concat(substring(.,7,4),substring(.,4,2),substring(.,1,2))=string(format-date(current-date(),"[Y][M01][D01]"))]]
```

**EDIT 2 :** To be complete, to keep records of the day with XPath 1.0, you have to enter manually the date of the day ("20190820" in the examples below, change it accordingly)

```
//*[last_modified[1][concat(substring(.,7,4),substring(.,4,2),substring(.,1,2))=20190820]]
/node[last_modified[1][concat(substring(.,7,4),substring(.,4,2),substring(.,1,2))=20190820]]
```

With XPath 2.0, the process to check the date should be automatic (but it seems the plugin doesn't support it) :

```
//*[last_modified[1][concat(substring(.,7,4),substring(.,4,2),substring(.,1,2))=string(format-date(current-date(),"[Y][M01][D01]"))]]
```

Comment: Hi There,

Thanks for the reply, I tried this but it doesn't seem to work. Does the format of my date matter? In the file it's "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM".

Comment: No. The XPath expression"rebuilds" your date and the current date in this format YYYYMMDD to compare them. 2 possibilies : i made a mistake in the XPath expression or WP doesn't support some XPath functions (format-date, current-date). Could you test :`/*[@last_modified[concat(substring(.,7,4),substring(.,4,2),substring(.,1,2))=string(format-date(current-date(),"[Y][M01][D01]"))]]`. Could you screenshot the XPath field when you add a rule (fill with anything you want equals 10 for example). I would like to check if we're working in the correct node.

Comment: Ah i see, I appreciate your help with this.  I've tried that new version and no luck with that either.

I've attached 3 screenshots showing the add rule logic and it filters when I just specify element contains "28/03/2020" as per screenshot 3:

https://imgur.com/a/zaHFkjM

Comment: OK. Post is edited with more options. If it still doesn't work, we'll have to check WP XPath 2.0 support.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work, does this mean that the plugin doesn't support Xpath 2.0? Do you know if Xpath 1 could solve this problem?

Comment: No chance with XPath 1.0. Your best bet is probably to ask them directly. Show them the last XPath expression and keep us in touch. https://www.wpallimport.com/support

Comment: Thank you I'll do that and report back

Comment: Hi Again,

I heard back from the plugin author and it is only xpath 1.0 that is used unfortunately.  Thanks for your time on this anyway.  The plugin creator has suggested to look at wp_all_import_is_post_to_update/create hooks instead to achieve this functionality

Comment: OK thanks. If it supports XPath 1.0 only, the expression I posted (see EDIT 2) should work...  If not as you stated a custom filter in PHP could do it : https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/developers/code-snippets/#filter-posts-by-date  In the example code you have to manually specify the date. For something automatic you'll have to use DateTime class :https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Comment: Thank you again for the valuable information.  After much thought I'm reviewing my options as to how to import best, I don't think WP All import is working for me as I'm trying to use it to import product attributes.

My product attributes labels are passed in one column in my CSV file and their values in the next column and no plugin effectively seems to be able to handle this as they all want the column header to be the attribute label. As I have thousands of attributes for different categories this is not possible. So I fear I've ran into a wall with this