# XPATH - Get all xml node less than 1 year from current date

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML file who looks like :

```
<product product_id="144446">
 <name>NAMEOFPRODUCT</name>
 <date>2020-05-19 00:00:00</date>
</product>
```

I'm trying to extract all products less than 1 year dynamically. I use a wordpress plugin (WP All Import) who allows me to filter xml results by xpath (PHP). For example to read all product I need to do : `/product`

Actually I managed to do this :

```
/product[substring(date[1], 1, 4) > "2019"]
```

It retrieve all products since 2019 but I need to change the string "2019" to change it with a dynamic function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This XPath + [php](/questions/tagged/php) variable:

```
$date = date("Y") -1;
$xpath = '//product[substring(./date, 1, 4) > ' . $date . ']';
# then doSomethingWithXpath($xpath);
```

Comment: As I said, I don't want to write the string "2019" I want something like : current_date - 1

Comment: Well I use a wordpress plugin who require XPath command. I think it's PHP !
Sorry I manage to do the first one by logic but I don't know what is xpath exactly,

Comment: I added some precisions

Comment: I cannot put php variable, just xpath in one command 
It's as you did before just transform with a function to current date

Answer (score 0):

XPath 2.0 expression to select products with date = actual year - 1

```
//product[date[number(substring(.,1,4))>=number(concat(year-from-date(current-date())-1,""))]]
```

If you need year, month and date precision :

```
//product[date[number(replace(substring(.,1,10),"-",""))>=number(replace(substring(concat(current-date(),""),1,10),"-",""))-10000]]
```

Sample :

```
<root>
<product product_id="144446">
 <name>NAMEOFPRODUCT</name>
 <date>2020-05-19 00:00:00</date>
</product>
<product product_id="144446">
 <name>NAMEOFPRODUCT</name>
 <date>2018-05-19 00:00:00</date>
</product>
<product product_id="144446">
 <name>NAMEOFPRODUCT</name>
 <date>2017-05-19 00:00:00</date>
</product>
<product product_id="144446">
 <name>NAMEOFPRODUCT</name>
 <date>2019-06-20 00:00:00</date>
</product>
<product product_id="144446">
 <name>NAMEOFPRODUCT</name>
 <date>2019-11-19 00:00:00</date>
</product>
</root>
```

First XPath will output 3 nodes.

```
NAMEOFPRODUCT 2020-05-19 00:00:00
NAMEOFPRODUCT 2019-06-20 00:00:00
NAMEOFPRODUCT 2019-11-19 00:00:00
```

Second XPath will output 2 nodes:

```
NAMEOFPRODUCT 2020-05-19 00:00:00
NAMEOFPRODUCT 2019-11-19 00:00:00
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer I think it's not too far but this doesn't work for me, maybe I use Xpath 1.0 ?

Comment: Yes, probably. Which XPath processor and programing language do you use ? AFAIK you can't do what you want with XPath 1.0 only. If you're using JS, Saxon JS supports XPath 2.0 expressions http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml As an alternative, you could create and store the current year in a variable (with JS, PHP, ...) . Then pass it to the XPath expression (XPath 1.0 compliant).

Comment: It seems you're using WP All Import. So SimpleXML, so no XPath 2.0. Reminds me a discussion I had here (bottom comments) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60883768/how-to-use-xpath-to-filter-out-date-field-in-wordpress-plugin I guess you'll have to write a function with PHP.